# PHP Login Logout problems

Tags: php

i tried to write `php` script for log in and log out. log in works fine but the problem is after i logged out when i hit back button it gets back to homepage.

```
<?php
//Start session
session_start();

//Include database connection details
require_once('connection.php');

//Array to store validation errors
$errmsg_arr = array();

//Validation error flag
$errflag = false;

//Function to sanitize values received from the form. Prevents SQL injection
function clean($str) {
    $str = @trim($str);
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $str = stripslashes($str);
    }
    return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
}

//Sanitize the POST values
$username = clean($_POST['username']);
$password = clean($_POST['password']);

//Input Validations
if($username == '') {
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'Username missing';
    $errflag = true;
}
if($password == '') {
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'Password missing';
    $errflag = true;
}

//If there are input validations, redirect back to the login form
if($errflag) {
    $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
    session_write_close();
    header("location: login.php");
    exit();
}

//Create query
$qry="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
$result=mysql_query($qry) or die (mysql_error());

//Check whether the query was successful or not
if($result) {
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        //Login Successful
        session_regenerate_id();
        $member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        $_SESSION['EmpId'] = $member['EmployeeId'];
        $_SESSION['username'] = $member['username'];
        $_SESSION['password'] = $member['password'];
        session_write_close();
        header("location: ../MyInfo.php");
        //echo 'You are loged in';
        exit();
    }else {
        //Login failed
        $errmsg_arr[] = 'user name and password not found';
        $errflag = true;
        if($errflag) {
            $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
            session_write_close();
            header("location: login.php");
            exit();
        }
    }
}else {
    die("Query failed");
}
?>

<?php
session_start(); // start a session first, else you cannot destroy/unset it
session_unset();
session_destroy(); // destroy all sessions
header('location:login.php'); // redirect   
?>
```

i hope u will help me thanks

Comment: You are storing the password in cleartext in the database?

Comment: Also in the session?!

Comment: `if(!isset($_SESSION))
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['EmpId'])
header("location: login.php");`

you have to add this code on all existant file with this logic

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this, added some key value in header `header('location:login.php?_k'.md5(tim()));`

```
    <?php
        session_start(); // start a session first, else you cannot destroy/unset it
        session_unset();
        session_destroy(); // destroy all sessions
        header('location:login.php?_k'.md5(tim())); // redirect   
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you checking if the sessions are valid?

From your code I would do

```
function checkIfLoggedIn()
{
   if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){ 
     header("Location:index.php");
   } else{
     header("Location:login.php");
   }
}
```

have that function right at the top of every page

Comment: It should be `header("location: login.php");`. Otherwise it is not doing anything.

Comment: Oops. Yes that should be it!!

Answer (score 0):

At the top of each php page, check to see if the user is logged in. If not, they should be redirected to a login page:

```
<?php 
      if(!isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) : 
      header("Location: login.php");  
?>
```